How to integrate uvicorn, FastAPI, Streamlit and Starlette to get App and API in same server/port?
I have a server that runs FastAPI endpoint with uvicorn on port 8080. I need to start a Streamlit application on the same port using other routes than the existing ones used by FastAPI. I can put the FastAPI routes under "/api/v1" and the Streamlit routes under "/app". I know starlette is used in FastAPI. How can I integrate these solutions in this use case (to get WebApp and API in same server/port but different routes)?

You can't have two servers running on the same port. If streamlit was based on WSGI, you could use FastAPI's mount, but unfortunately it is not:

Streamlit does not support the WSGI protocol at this time, so
deploying Streamlit with (for example) gunicorn is not currently
possible

What you can do is use a reverse proxy like nginx or an apigateway like spring cloud gateway or kong to serve both services.
